# Rerouting options under EC261

Tags: cancellations, passenger-rights, ec261

We are a party of four with a one-way flight from New York to Paris with one stop in Porto, Portugal on TAP Airlines.  The flight is not for a few months yet but the third party that we purchased the tickets from just notified us that the flight was cancelled and that TAP offered an alternate itinerary or a refund.  We do not want a refund but the alternate itinerary offered does not work well for us based on other flights and hotels that are scheduled before and after this one.  I see plenty of other itineraries available with TAP from New York to Paris on the same day as our original, albeit going through JFK or LIS rather and EWR and OPO.  What are are rights (if any) on requesting additional options from TAP that come closer to our original departure and arrival times?

Comment: Have you contacted the airline and discussed alternatives with them?

Comment: As long as there are actual availabilities, airlines are usually quite flexible in rerouting options, you just need to contact them (which may be the hard part nowadays). Having detailed alternatives already on hand helps a lot. Note that they may have information about flights they expect to be cancelled that have not yet been made public, and of course there’s the possibility that any flight you are rebooked onto will be cancelled as well, so keep your options open.

Comment: So far, I have only sent a response to the third party that notified me of the cancellation; no response yet. I wanted to be a little more informed about my rights before reaching out to the airline directly in case I got a hold of a customer rep who is a little less than helpful.
Thank you for the feedback!  I agree that having some alternate routes/itineraries could make it easier for an airline rep to help me.